# How to get all titles with child from one table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

i have a table like this:

| id | title | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | title1 | null |
| 2 | title2 | 1 |
| 3 | title3 | 1 |
| 4 | title4 | 2 |
| 5 | title5 | 2 |
| 6 | title6 | 3 |

i want to display all rows which have id in column ***parent_id*** so that the result is:

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | title1 |
| 2 | title2 |
| 3 | title3 |

Comment: But row with id = 1 does NOT have _id in column parent_id_. Why do you include it and exclude others that DO have a non-null value?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `EXISTS` subquery

```
SELECT id,title
FROM T t1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM T tt
    WHERE tt.parent_id = t1.id
)
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=920ad285db4cd126328cbcf4213fb92f)

Answer (score 0):

You can just check for `NULL`, there is no need to join

```sql
SELECT
  t.id,
  t.title
FROM YourTable t
WHERE t.parent_id IS NOT NULL;
```